# Get full Facebook data

Tags: facebook, json, facebook-graph-api

Can I use Facebook Graph API to download my full Facebook data? I've tried Graph API Explorer and I can only see all of them, but independently. Is it possible to get all the data in just one request or one json structure? and is it possible to include all of my friends data too?

My friend did show me a json file that contains such data and it's quite a big file(480Mb uncompressed, 48Mb compressed). Apparently, I can't contact her now  for more details. Is it possible to this? If I can't, can I assume that she downloaded her data long before Facebook changed their privacy agreement?

Answer (score 2):

you can also use netvizz an app in facebook itself.It gives you the whole network in .gdf format .
Then you can analyze it in gephi(its just another way around